# Specialist Hatsman - When is it earned?

Tags: support, winter-bash-2015

The [Specialist Hatsman](http://winterbash2015.stackexchange.com/specialist-hatsman):

> collect 11 hats

So once you collected 11 hats, you'll get the 12<sup>th</sup> one.

[This user](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4099598/nathan-tuggy#) has collected 11 hats, and still didn't get the *Specialist Hatsman* hat. Is it because he earn some of the hats on different sites? If so, I think the description is a bit misleading, specially because the fact that there is no separation between hats on different sites - all of them can be viewed in the same place regardless of the site.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it because he earn some of the hats on different sites?

That's right. You get Specialist Hatsman if you earn 11 hats on one site.

I think this makes more sense than if you would get it if you got 11 hats over the whole network, because in case of the latter, it would be hard to decide on which site you would get Specialist Hatsman.

Comment: Not to mention that it would be trivially easy to collect 1 hat on each of 11 sites.

Comment: I totally misunderstood the hat.. Thanks